# TypeORM Concrete Table & relation with other tables

Tags: inheritance, nestjs, typeorm

I have Classes Called User , Page , Element & Class Element is an abstract class that will be the base class.
then i will have different classes extend Element (ex: Element1,Element2...).

**Class Element:**

```js
    export abstract class Element extends BaseEntity {
    
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;
        
        //Adding other common Fields...
    
        @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.blocks, { eager: false })
        @JoinColumn({name:"userId"})
        user: User;
        @Exclude()
        @Column({ select: false })
        userId: number;
    
    
        @ManyToOne(type => Page, page => page.elements, { eager: false })//error 
        @JoinColumn({name:"pageId"})
        page: Page;
        @Column()
        pageId: number;
    
    }
```

**Class Page:**

```js
    @Entity()
    export class Page extends BaseEntity {
    
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;
    
         //Adding other Fields...
    
        @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.pages, { eager: false })
        @JoinColumn({name:"userId"})
        user: User;
        @Exclude()
        @Column({ select: false })
        userId: number;

        //relation with element
        @OneToMany(type => Element, element=> element.page, { eager: true })//error
        elements: Element[] | null;
    
    }
```

**Class User:**

```js
    @Entity()
    @Unique(["email"])
    export class User extends BaseEntity {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;
      
          //Adding other Fields...

        //relation with page
        @OneToMany(type => Page, page => page.user,{ eager: true })
        pages: Page[];
    
        //relation with block
        @OneToMany(type => Element, element=> element.user,{ eager: true })
        elements: Element[];
    
    }
```

**Class Element1:**

```js
    @Entity()
    export class Element1 extends Element{
    
       //Adding other Fields..
    
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +65ms
Error: Entity metadata for Page#elements was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options
```

**My Question:**

1-Did I write the code for TypeORM Concrete Table correctly?

2-If it's correct? is the problem because defining relation inside Class Element (basetype) not within the subtype classes?

3-last, Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: After a year, I didn't find a solution for this.
I think after reading some other questions that it has something to do with multiple tables having the same foreign key (I mean, with same name)
BaseEntity will create a table Element table with (id, userId (fk)
If BaseEntity has another child class it will leverage to another table with userId as fk again with the same name.

Comment: @Danilo Marques
you can check this & give your thought https://github.com/magician20/pagee-smooth/tree/master/src/block